# How to delete characters that appear more than once in a string, and keep only the first character and return the result

Tags: java, string, methods, handler

How to delete characters that appear more than once in a string, and keep only the first character and return the result?

Example:

input: String bananas
output: String bans

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a local variable to hold an empty String
2. Loop thru the input string
3. Keep appending the current character to local variable as long as local variable doesn't contain the character at the current position

   ```
    String s1 = "";
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (!s1.contains("" + s.charAt(i))){
            s1 += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid `char`

When working with individual characters one-by-one, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers. You will often see `char` primitives or `Character` objects being used, but that type has been **essentially broken** since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5.

## Code points

You can get the code points of a string's characters as an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) by calling [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()). From there we eliminate duplicates by calling [`IntStream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct()). The remaining code point `int` values can be collected by [appending](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint(int)) to a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object. Lastly, we convert the mutable `StringBuilder` to an immutable `String` object.

```java
String distinct =
        "bananas"
                .codePoints()
                .distinct()
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lQVnAR).

> bans

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an interview question.
Try the following steps:

1. create int[26]- holds visit count for each letter assuming inputs
   are always lowercase
2. loop thru the input

   - append to the output when the letter is not visited
   - update the visit count